# Open for "anyone"? Or open for "everyone"?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, any-every

Is the tournament open for "anyone" or "everyone"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a subtle distinction, as noted  that's likely unimportant -- unless you're at all concerned about subconscious reactions from speakers of American English.

"Anyone" does have some negative connotations and usages attached to it that people don't necessarily think about:

- "*Anyone* can do that."
- "They'll take *anyone*."

For your purposes either would probably be fine, but "everyone" will be perceived as more inclusive.

Answer (score 13):

The distinction is not important in this case. *Everyone* means every person, without exception and *anyone* means any person, without discrimination.

Comment: Perfect answer, this one should be the preferred answer of this question.

Answer (score 6):

Usually a tournament would be "open to everyone" or "open to anyone".

To me there is a marginal difference that "open to everyone" sounds slightly more friendly or more welcoming than "open to anyone".

Comment: True - I think the difference stems from "anyone" sounding as if there is a singular selection to be made, and "everyone" sounding very much plural.

Answer (score 2):

If you are suggesting you would be happy with one (any one) response, which could hypothetically be the case if the condition is that 'there are no restrictions: *anyone* can participate', then you can use *anyone*. You don't care who comes.

On the other hand, as may be more likely, if you would like as many as possibly can to participate, you'd be saying *everyone*. You do want everyone to come.

This is based on how the reader would more generally perceive.

Answer (score 0):

"every" as in "each and every" is a reference to elements in a set and can be taken as the intention to include all elements in the set; "any" is more a universal concept and implies no distinction at all.