# "anybody can dance" or "Everybody can dance"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

"Anybody can dance" or "Everybody can dance", which is correct? Or do they have same meaning?

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: @jwpat7: I have posted the same there too. But no, response.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/open-for-anyone-or-open-for-everyone and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72984/anyone-and-everyone-correct-usage, or also this http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77058/what-is-the-difference-between-anyone-and-everyone-in-this-context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there is nothing wrong grammatically with either of your sentences, there are a couple of potential problems with interpretation that I can see.

Strictly speaking, the word *can* means 'is **able** to'. If you are saying that everybody **is able to** dance then I present myself as living evidence to the contrary. Your intended meaning is more likely to be 'Anybody **may** dance', meaning that anybody is **permitted** to dance. Having said that, *can* is a commonly used informal replacement for *may*.

As to *anybody* vs *everybody*, the distinction in your context is minor. *Anybody* means zero or more of a given population, whereas *everybody* means all of a given population. Saying 'anybody may dance' implies that dancing is not restricted to a select few (probably the intended meaning). Saying 'everybody may dance' means pretty much the same thing, perhaps with the added implication that it would not be a problem should everyone decide to get up and boogie simultaneously.

A case where the distinction is important might be as follows. A group of people hire a bus for a day trip. The lady behind the counter at the bus hire company might tell you 'Anybody can drive the bus', but if she said 'Everybody can drive the bus' you would probably raise an eyebrow.

Comment: Planned to give a +1 for that `lady behind the counter`. But, not enough rep to do so :(

Comment: "Strictly speaking, the word _can_ means 'is able to'." _ I think this claims too much authority for the assertion, and would prefer that the sentence adverbial be replaced by 'In formal registers'. Having said that, you do go on to ameliorate the prescriptive stance. The AHD has a nice article on usage at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/can .

Comment: That's a good description of the "free choice" modal polarity _any_ (notice that _any_ is ungrammatical in a subject NP without a negative unless there is a modal like _can, may,_ or _will_ in the clause -- _*Anybody is dancing right now._). Modal polarity _any_ is different from the negative polarity _any_ of _I didn't dance with anybody_.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth: good point, conceded. John Lawler: a whole slew of good points which I wouldn't be capable of making.

Answer (score 1):

> A: Who should I dance with?
>   B1: Dance with anybody!

(Meaning don't be choosy -- one partner is as good as the next)

> B2: Dance with everybody!

(Meaning leave nobody undanced with: you have a long night's dancing ahead of you)

> By the end of the song, **everybody** in the stadium was dancing with Lenart Krone, but Lenart was dancing alone. [...]
>   **Anybody** can dance. You don't have to be Red Adair; just close your eyes and let the music lead you.

Example of usage:

> A: You need to talk to **somebody**.
>   B: Who?
>   A: **Anybody**. Just talk. You'll feel better.

Comment: Welcome to ELU!  Unfortunately I don't understand how this addresses the actual question?

Comment: @Chenmunka and Hellion the poster has indeed attempted to answer the question by illustrating how "anybody", "everybody" and "somebody" is used in everyday speech.